# How to highlight each line using ACE Editor in Angular TypeScript?

Tags: angular5, ace-editor

I use ACE Editor in my Angular5 project.
As you can see I want to validate allow and deny email in the editor. 
I want to highlight each line that is duplicated.
ACE Editor can be highlighted each line like that?
Please see 
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN46Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **addMarker** to add highlight to the lines you want to show a highlight.

```
Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;
editor.session.addMarker(
    new Range(from, start_pos, to, end_pos), 
    "show-highlight", 
    "fullLine");
```

Here start_pos and end_pos are the lines you would like to highlight. Add CSS to the class "show-highlight"

```
.show-highlight {
  position:absolute;
  background: yellow; //Specify the color you would like to use
}
```